# E0137: выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

я пытаюсь создать игру "жизнь" на C++ с помощью двумерных массивов, однако не знаю как заполнить массивы.
выдаёт ошибку: E0137    выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

```
const size_t w = 3;
const size_t h = 3;
int m[w];
int map[h][w] = { {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1} };

for (int count = 0; count < w; count++) { m[count] = 1; }
for (int count = 0; count < h; count++) { map[count] = m;}
```

Comment: *однако не знаю как заполнить массивы* Гуглим "заполнение двумерные массивы с++". Находим: https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-array-tutorial-part-2/#_3 Скроллим вниз до заголовка "Заполнение массива значениями". Ушло 2 минуты. Самому слабо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int map[h][w]
```

Значит, `map[count]` - это просто массив `int[w]`. И как вы собираетесь присваивать что-то *массиву*?...

Comment: забыл немного поправить код и поменять ` map[count] = h;` на ` map[count] = m;`